# If a end time value has NULL, Replace the value with next start time of same id

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hql, hiveql

I have a table with 3 fields.

- Start_time
- End_time
- ID

If the end time is `NULL`, I need to replace with nearest time of same `ID`.

```
----------------------------------
| ID | Start_time  |    End_time |
----------------------------------
| 1  | 2016-01-01  |        NULL |
| 2  | 2016-01-01  |  2016-01-02 |
| 1  | 2016-01-02  |  2016-01-03 |
| 1  | 2016-01-03  |  2016-01-04 |
```

Expected Output

```
---------------------------------
| ID | Start_time |    End_time |
---------------------------------
| 1  | 2016-01-01 |  2016-01-02 |
| 2  | 2016-01-01 |  2016-01-02 |
| 1  | 2016-01-02 |  2016-01-03 |
| 1  | 2016-01-03 |  2016-01-04 |
```

Comment: Your expected results don't match your description of what they should be. If you need to select closest time **with the same ID**, then for ID=1 it should be `2016-01-03` and not `2016-01-02`, as it has an ID=2

Comment: Also, define **nearest time**: is it closest by absolute value, latest preceding, or earliest succeeding?

Comment: Latest preceding

Comment: Latest preceding based on what columns? There should be some column/columns you are using to define the ordering. You can use LEAD/LAG functions accordingly with `case when`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use subquery grouping for id for obtain the min end_time

```
  select a.id, a.Start_time
      , case when a.End_time is null then t.min_end_time else  a.End_time end End_time 
  from my_table 
  inner join (
  select id, min(End_time) min_end_time
  from my_table 
  group by id ) t on t.id = a.id
```

Comment: Not the minimum end time but next preceding value I need